# debian nginx 1.10.3 prevent headers injection

Tags: nginx, debian-jessie, symfony, host-headers

I have a debian 8 VPS running with nginx 1.10.3.

I host several Symfony 3.2 websites (using php7-fpm), and I face headers injection problems. I can't figure out if the problem is more from nginx or from the symfony  project configuration.

I am not using any LoadBalancer like Varnish or Amazon AWS for now.

When someone sends a request using an invalid `X-Forwared-Host` such as :

`X-Forwarded-Host: pg_sleep(2)`

Then it receives a `500 Internal Server Error`, and I can see a critical error in the logs:

`UnexpectedValueException: "Invalid Host "pg_sleep(2)" at [...]/var/bootstrap.php.cache"`

I can easily reproduce it (only on production environment, using this bootstrap.php.cache file) with curl :

```
curl -I\
 -H "X-Forwarded-Host: pg_sleep(2)"\
 "https://my-domain.tld"
```

Some other values I got can be `X-Forwarded-Host: *.domain.tld`, `X-Forwarded-Host: -1 or 2+429-429-1=0+0+0+1 --`, `X-Forwarded-Host: -1; waitfor delay '0:0:14' --` etc.

I looks like an injection attack.

My goal is to handle such invalid headers and return for instance a 444 status, or at least prevent the application to trigger `500 Internal Server Error`.

My first question is : should I try to intercept such unvalid headers inside nginx configuration (using a module ?) or is it something that should be handled by the symfony project instead ?

I have read this guide : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html

> You should also make sure that your proxy filters unauthorized use of these headers, e.g. if a proxy natively uses the X-Forwarded-For header, it should not allow clients to send Forwarded headers to Symfony.

Which makes me think this should by handled by nginx, then... How?

I have tried to check the host inside my server{} block, but it doesn't intercept it...

```
server {
    listen 443;

    # [...]

    if ($host !~ ^(my-domain.tld)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    # [...]
}
```

I looks like it could be possible to use the `headers_more` module, but is it the best practice?

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

Comment: Why not just strip the header? `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host "";`. This sets header value to void causing the header to be excluded from headers passed to PHP-FPM. You can read more about that here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header. This will not let you intercept it, but instead will just ignore the header.

Comment: I have followed the recipe of Symfony, which uses fastcgi instead of proxies... Do you recommend switching the configuration to proxy instead?
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/

Comment: I'd definitely use fastcgi over proxy, yes.